# Select all unique third octet in a list of IP addresses with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a list of IP addresses. They all start with 10.10. I want all the unique values of the third octet. This way I can count how many of that unique value there are.

```
10.10.26.251
10.10.27.221
10.10.26.55
10.10.31.12
10.10.12.31
10.10.31.11
10.10.27.15
10.10.26.5
```

When I am done I want to know that I have 3 .26 network devices, 2 27, and so on so forth. Other than breaking down the octet with a split and looping through each one, I can't think of any single liners. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a small variant. [*grin*] i already had this before noticing the other answers - and it is a tad different.

what it does ...

- creates a collection of IPv4 address objects to work with
- groups them by a calculated property [the 3rd octet]
- creates a `[PSCustomObject]` for each resulting group
- sends it to the `$Octet3_Report` variable
- shows it on screen

output to a CSV file would be easy at that point. here's the code ...

```
$IP_List = @(
    [ipaddress]'10.10.26.251'
    [ipaddress]'10.10.27.221'
    [ipaddress]'10.10.26.55'
    [ipaddress]'10.10.31.12'
    [ipaddress]'10.10.12.31'
    [ipaddress]'10.10.31.11'
    [ipaddress]'10.10.27.15'
    [ipaddress]'10.10.26.5'
    )

$Octet3_Report = $IP_List |
    Group-Object -Property {$_.ToString().Split('.')[2]} |
    ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Octet_3 = $_.Name
            Count = $_.Count
            }
        }

$Octet3_Report
```

on screen output ...

```
Octet_3 Count
------- -----
26          3
27          2
31          2
12          1
```

Answer (score 0):

It's like me to figure it out after the fact.
The Return contains the dns records. The IP address are stored inside recorddata. I pull the end of the IP address off. Then loop through grabbing only the range and count with a foreach loop to make it cleaner.

```
$DNSRecordCounts = @()
$Ranges = ($Return | where-object {$_.recorddata -like "10.10.*"}).recorddata -replace "\.\d{1,3}$" | select -Unique
foreach ($range in $Ranges) {
     $DNSRecordCounts += [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
          IPRange = $range
          Count = ($Return | Where-Object {$_.recorddata -like "$($range).*"}).Count
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question and what I can infer from your own answer, if you are looking for something a little more like "idiomatic" PowerShell you want the following:

```
$Return `
| Select-Object -ExpandProperty recorddata `
| ForEach-Object {
    $_ -match "\d+\.\d+\.(?<octet>\d+)\.\d+" | Out-Null
    $Matches.octet
} `
| Group-Object `
| ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Octet = $_.Name
        Count = $_.Count
    }
}
```